# Java - Ensuring an item from a collection can only be used once

Tags: java, if-statement, hashmap, conditional-statements, aggregation

So I'm trying to ensure that if a certain item from a static hashmap is used more than once, then it doesn't allow you to use it again. The idea behind the program is that a Scout squad can't have more than one "heavy bolter" and "missle launcher" per squad. Note that "heavy bolter" and "missle launcher" are two hashmap keys in a hashmap collection.

So I have a class called WeaponList which holds a static hashmap of Ranged weapons. And then I have a Scout class that allows a Scout to upgrade it's ranged weapon from the default one set in the constructor. However some items in the WeaponList classes hashmap should only be allowed to be upgraded to once. So if a Scout upgrades to a "Heavy Bolter" and there is already a squad member with that weapon already,  the upgrade should not occur.

Is there a way to do this? I already tried this line of code in the Scout classes upgradeRanged method. `if (WeaponList.getRanged("Heavy Bolter") > 1))` But thats not working because I think using the '>' symbol doesn't work between primtive and Reference types.

I should also mention that I have another class called ScoutSquad which is an aggregation of Scouts. In the main program you create a ScoutSquad Object reference and then add Scout objects to the ScoutSquad. Each Scout can individualy upgrade their default weapons. (I was maybe thinking about using the ScoutSquad class to ensure that a Ranged weapon from the HashMap can't be used more than once).

Any help with this would be appericated, and if theres any confusion with the question le tme know and i'll make the appropiate changes.

I'll now provide the code for the relavant classes:

WeaponList Class

```
public class WeaponList
{
    static Map<String, Ranged> rangedlist = new HashMap<String, Ranged>()
    {{          
        put("Bolter", new Ranged2H("Bolter", 1));
        put("Bolt Pistol", new Ranged("Bolt Pistol", 1));
        put("Flamer", new Ranged2H("Flamer", 1));
        put("Meltagun", new Ranged2H("Meltagun", 1));
        put("Plasma Gun", new Ranged2H("Plasma Gun", 1));
        put("Plasma Pistol", new Ranged("Plasma Pistol", 10));
        put("Shotgun", new Ranged2H("Shotgun", 10));
        put("Sniper Rifle", new Ranged2H("Sniper Rifle", 5));

        put("Assault Cannon", new Ranged2H("Assault Cannon", 10));
        put("Cyclone Missle Launcher", new Ranged2H("Cyclone Missle Launcher", 10));
        put("Heavy Bolter", new Ranged2H("Heavy Bolter", 10));
        put("Heavy Flamer", new Ranged2H("Heavy Flamer", 10));
        put("Assault Cannon", new Ranged2H("Lascannon", 10));
        put("Missle Launcher", new Ranged2H("Missle Launcher", 10));
        put("Multi Melta", new Ranged2H("Multi Melta", 10));
        put("Plasma Cannon", new Ranged2H("Plasma Cannon", 10));   
    }};

    public static Ranged getRanged(String index)
    {       
        return rangedlist.get(index);   
    }

    public static Map<String, Ranged> getRangedList()
    {           
        return rangedlist;
    }
}
```

Scout class (focus on the upgradeRanged method)

```
public class Scout
{
    private Weapon ranged;
    private int points;

    //DEFAULT SCOUT
    public Scout() 
    {       
        ranged = new Ranged("Bolt Pistol", 0);

        points = 13; 
        points = points + ranged.getWeaponPoints();      
    }

    public void rangedUpgrade(Ranged ranged) 
    {    
        switch(ranged.toString())
        {
            case "Bolter" : 
            case "Shotgun" :
            case "Sniper Rifle" : 
            case "Heavy Bolter" : 
            case "Missle Launcher" :            
               this.ranged = ranged; 
               points = points + ranged.getWeaponPoints();
            break;        
            default :
                System.out.println("A Scout can't have a " + ranged);                   
        }

        if (WeaponList.getRanged("Heavy Bolter") > 1))
        {

        }
    }  

    public Weapon getRangedUpgrade()
    {
        return ranged;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "|| " + "Ranged Weapon: " + ranged + " || " + "Melee Weapon: " + melee + " || " + "Points: " + points;
    }
}
```

Main program:

```
public class ArmyBuilderDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {       
        ScoutSquad scouts = new ScoutSquad("Squad 1");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the squad size: ");
        int size = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            scouts.addScout(new Scout());

        System.out.println(scouts.getScoutSquad());

        scouts.getScout(5).rangedUpgrade(WeaponList.getRanged("Heavy Bolter"));

        System.out.println(scouts.getScoutSquad());

      input.close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Map.get() returns the object not the count. You may need to explicitly convert to the respective object and get the attributes (count in your case) .

Comment: @Kajal Right okay, thats sounds a bit advanced to me. I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: You said "I was maybe thinking about using the ScoutSquad class to ensure that a Ranged weapon from the HashMap can't be used more than once" -- I think that's a good idea, and the better approach. In a given squad, you count the number of scouts that use the thing you want to be used at most N times. That's where this logic belongs, if I understand correctly. Not in the global map.

Comment: @HuguesMoreau Yeah so maybe I could have a count of all the times a scout upgrades to a "heavy bolter" and if thats greater than 1, then something happens such as a print statement. However I'm not sure how this might would stop the scout from upgrading to a weapon thats only allowed to be upgraded too once.

Comment: @HuguesMoreau I think i've got a rough idea, what i need to do, but i'm not quite sure how i might implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in **ScoutSquad** Class:

```
public boolean checkUses(String weapon) {
  for (Scout scout : scouts)
    if (scout.getRangedUpgrade() == WeaponList.getRanged(weapon)
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

Change the *rangedUpgrade* method of **Scout** Class:

```
public void rangedUpgrade(Ranged ranged) 
        {    
            switch(ranged.toString())
            {
                case "Heavy Bolter" : 
                case "Missle Launcher" :            
                  if (getSquad().checkUses(ranged.toString())) {
                    System.out.println(
                    "This scout's squad is already using a " + ranged);
                    break;
                  }
                case "Bolter" : 
                case "Shotgun" :
                case "Sniper Rifle" : 
                    this.ranged = ranged; 
                    points = points + ranged.getWeaponPoints();
                break;        
                default :
                    System.out.println("A Scout can't have a " + ranged);                   
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap.get()` returns `null` if the item is not present in the `Map`. Hence you can do:

```
if(WeaponList.getRanged("Heavy Bolter") != null) {
    // Already has
else {
    // Doesn't have
}
```

Comment: That just ensures the item is in the HashMap no? I want it so only one of certain items from that HashMap can be assigned to each squad Unless i'm looking at it wrong.